# Calculating Download Speed

Tags: java, stream

I am downloading a file but trying to also determine the download speed in KBps. I came up with an equation, but it is giving strange results.

```
    try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int read = 0;
        while (true) {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            if ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            } else {
                break;
            }
            int speed = (int) ((read * 1000000000.0) / ((System.nanoTime() - start) * 1024.0));
        }
    }
```

It's giving me anywhere between 100 and 300,000. How can I make this give the correct download speed? Thanks

Comment: `nanoTime` is rarely even close to accurate. Do you have to report the download speed while downloading or after the download finished ?

Comment: @SoboLAN While downloading. What else could I use other than nanoTime? I don't think `currentTimeMillis` would work either.

Answer (score 2):

You are not checking your currentAmmount and previousAmount of file downloading.

example

```
int currentAmount = 0;//set this during each loop of the download
/***/
int previousAmount = 0;
int firingTime = 1000;//in milliseconds, here fire every second
public synchronyzed void run(){
    int bytesPerSecond = (currentAmount-previousAmount)/(firingTime/1000);
    //update GUI using bytesPerSecond
    previousAmount = currentAmount;    
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your code a little bit more ? I mean, can you post the full code please ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you are calculating `read()` time + `write()` time in very short intervals and the result will vary depending on the (disk cache) flushing of the writes().
Put the calculation right after the `read()`


Second, your buffer size (4096) probably does not match the tcp buffer size  (yours is eventually  smaller), and because of that some reads will be very fast (because it is read from the local TCP buffer). Use `Socket.getReceiveBufferSize()`
and set the size of your buffer accordingly (let say 2* the size of TCP recv buf size) and fill it in a *nested loop until full* before calculating.